# Programmatically Tap View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created a custom view that is to be used as a radio button with images and text. I need to be able to load the saved selection when the controller loads. I set my listeners this way:

```
for button in genderButtons {
    button.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(genderTapped(_:))))
}

@objc private func genderTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    for button in genderButtons {
        button.select(sender.view! == button) // Toggles the button to display selected/deslected state.

        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to tell the view to select. I tried making the gesture recognizer and object, but it doesn't have any methods I can use to trigger it. The 'buttons' aren't actually buttons, they're views, so I can't send an action event.

How can I select the correct button with code?

Comment: are you not able to find the correct view tapped? or you are not able to change the state of the view to selected?

Comment: Instead of subclassing your buttons to inherent from `UIView`, subclass them to inherent from `UIControl` instead (which itself inherts from `UIView`). They function just like views do but controls allow you to post action updates and they're better suited to handle touch events which you can handle using methods like `touchesBegan(_:with:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `genderTapped` directly, handing it the gesture recognizer already attached to the desired "button".

For example, if `thisGenderButton` is the one you want to "tap", say:

```
if let tap = thisGenderButton.gestureRecognizers?[0] as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
    genderTapped(tap)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method in your customView like this,

```
Class CustomView: UIView {

    public func select(_ value: Bool) {
       self.backgroundColor = value ? .green: .red
    }
}
```

and then in below method you can call `select` for the tapped view.

```
@objc private func genderTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   (sender.view as? CustomView)?.select(true)
}
```

Comment: no need to add tag, You can directly use `sender.view?.select(true)` in `func genderTapped`

Comment: I already have a tag. What your suggesting is what's already done. What I need to do is be able to make a specific button call the genderTapped() function when necessary.

Comment: @CodyHarness Do you want a callback when a button inside a `CustomView` is tapped?